# When sending an array of bytes via networkstream, extra characters appear in the final file

Tags: c#, .net

Send an array of bytes

```
    public static void SendFile(string path)
    {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

Getting the byte array

```
    List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
    byte[] data = new byte[64]; 
    int bytes = 0;

    do
    {
        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(data[i]);
            }

     } while (stream.DataAvailable);

     return list.ToArray();
```

Creating a file

```
     byte[] file = ReciveFile().ToArray();
     File.WriteAllBytes(message, file);
```

Appear extra characters like these

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm2es.jpg)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH4rV.jpg)

**How to fix?** Thanks

Comment: You are reading form the stream incorrectly. You seem to be getting the amount of bytes read and then totally ignoring the value. its like taking a bucket to someone and asking them to put stuff in it, they tell you how much they give you, but you ignore them and pretend its a full bucket. Best to go and read the documentation or better examples on how to read from a network stream

Comment: Also the whole `DataAvailable` thing is not going to work

Comment: `list.AddRange` may also be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how many bytes were read. Otherwise the end of your buffer may contain garbage if the file's length isn't an exact multiple of 64.

```
do
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)  //use bytes, not data.Length
        {
            list.Add(data[i]);
        }

 } while (bytes > 0);
```